# How to encrypt primary keys in a consistent way

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I've got a database table that has a simple incrementing integer as the primary key (1,2,3 etc). These numbers represent the alumni of a college, with personal information in the records. I've been asked to give each record a unique ID when displayed to the user (after they've queried the database) but the ID must not be the primary key, and it must be consistent.

If someone retrieved a record with the arbitrary ID 88gh344r, for example, then did another search and retrieved record 88gh344r again they need to be able to say "That's the same person". Since people need to be able to recognise the identifier from one search to the next, then the ID can't be long and complex.

I've thought of three approaches:

1. Create an extra table containing the primary key and a random sequence of numbers, and get the query to retrieve the random number equivalent of the primary key.
2. Encrypt the primary key using MySQL's SHA2 or AES, but these produce long letter and digit sequences.
3. Encrypt the Primary key on the fly in the query, using something like Base64 encryption in PHP.

Which of these is best, or have I missed a better approach?

Comment: what about if ( USER || PERMISSION ) { //show stuffs } else { exit; } ?

Answer (score 1):

I actually just wrote a short tut on a URL shortener that works on that basis, using a recid as the seed. you could use that function to create your lookup key and store it in the DB as the "reference" key  the code is [here](http://php4.me/)

Comment: Thanks for the link - that's an interesting tutorial in itself!

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it to protect privacy, you're heading for a major fsckup. It won't take long for the lamest script kiddie to write a simple program which just tries every possibile "hash", dowloading your entire list.

You should look into proper access control so people can see only what they're allowed to see.

Comment: What would access control be in this context? Anyone will be free to search the database - there's no login or authorization of another kind. As long as people don't get the primary key, then the rest of the info is fine.

Comment: @Beasley: why can't the primary key be seen by the end user? It's a number.

Comment: Just posted this below: I need to encrypt the primary key because there's a published register of alumni using exactly the same numbering system! If I didn't encrypt them, people would simply consult number 2 (for example) in the printed register and find out who it was. The website will be a resource for academics. They want to see the personal information, but aren't interested exactly who it is. They just want to know how many people who graduated in 1959 became teachers, for example. The printed register contains names, but very little personal information.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your main goal is just not to reveal the primary keys, but use something else instead when communicating with the users.

Simplest way:

add an CHAR column to your table and choose some length you want the other identifiers to be, for example CHAR(16).

give UNIQUE index to that column, so that you won't have any duplicates.

for each row generate a *secure* *random* string of length 16 and update the row.

DO NOT hash the plain primary key. If the keys start from 1,2,3.. then everybody can match the `id` to the `hash` by just calculating hashes for 1,2,3 .... etc

Another problem is that if you for example already have 200 rows in the table and you add 1, then the attacker can automatically associate the primary key 201 to the random string that just appeared in the list.

On the other hand, why do you need to hide the primary keys in the first place. Maybe you should instead encrypt the personal user data in the columns?

Comment: Thanks for that clear answer. Yes, you understand me correctly. I need to encrypt the primary key because there's a published register of alumni using exactly the same numbering system! If I didn't encrypt them, people would simply consult number 2 (for example) on the register and find out who it was. It's a resource for academics. They want to see the personal information, but aren't interested exactly who it is. They just want to know how many people who graduated in 1959 became teachers, for example.

Comment: Forgot to ask - what would be the best way to generate the random strings in the new CHAR column? There are 6,000 records. Write a PHP function like [this](http://www.lost-in-code.com/programming/php-code/php-random-string-with-numbers-and-letters/)?

Comment: I'm personally a fan of PHP 5.3's [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) to fetch pseudo-random alphanumerics.  For example, `echo substr(preg_replace('/\W/', '', base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16))), 0, 16)`

Comment: Just seen [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) in the PHP manual, too. Lots of approaches given in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

*Don't make it too complicated.*

Consider this:

1. The user is given an alternative mapping key. This can be a temporary session mapping and/or a secondary unique key (but is *not* the PK and may or may not be in the same table) and should, of course, be unique with the domain.
2. Access token, randomly generated per item but need not be unique, which is combined with a simple PK for the exposed id. This can be made to look pretty across values with appropriate transformation if desired. The access token may also be treated as a separate value.

I like the second approach. In both cases it is not the "direct PK" which is exposed although there is more coupling in the 2nd form.

Both of these will prevent the "knowing" the next key based off a sequence, but guessing/brute-force is tied to the size of the domain: as others have said, this shouldn't be used as primary security layer.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a base 36 encode on the userid*100 or something, for example.

userid 26=208
userid 3=8C

http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/units-converter/numbers/calculator/decimal-to-base-36

Comment: Thanks - that's a simple idea worth thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate a hash or an encrypted value to the desired length, but with both you risk a collision. With eight base-36 digits you have about a 50% [chance of a collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) if you have 2 million records. If you don't convert to base-36 and just take eight hexadecimal digits, you only need 80 thousand records.

With random numbers you don't have this problem, because you can put a uniqueness constraint on the column and generate a new number if a collision occurs.

Answer (score 0):

the short answer that I found after 2 month search is `hashids` that you can install it for every language from https://hashids.org/ .Its options are:

1. generate encrytion string from a key that called salt.
2. define min-length for your string for example 8 digits that it's unavailable for functions like base64_encode()
3. reverse decode your string
4. define your desired alphabets for example a-z only.(note that 16 alphabet must defined at least)

***note:*** for `php` it is recommended to activate `bcmath` and `GMP` extensions for your website host but it works without `GMP`.